# Ansicon crashes my ruby Windows 8

Tags: ruby, windows, installation

I am doing some cucumber testing so that I tried to install ansicon in order to ease my life. I am running 64 bit Windows 8 and I tried the following:

```
ansicon.exe -i
ansicon.exe -p
```

even starting the ansicon from a shortcut, but every time when I run calabash-android my ruby (1.9.3) crashes... any ideas why?

Comment: The latest version of Ansicon (v1.66) seems to fix it on my Windows 8.1 machine. See: http://adoxa.hostmyway.net/ansicon/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue with rspec.

The solution outlined below is what ended up working for me.   https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/issues/61

Basically, I ended up swapping out my ANSI64.dll with the one located here: 
https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=0D18DE9C2F9D17ED&id=D18DE9C2F9D17ED!111

Hope that works for you!